# How to get name(label) of the checkbox

Tags: scripting, interface, properties

As an example of a checkbox, I took Viewport Denoising (You can see it in the picture). I have a checkbox and I want to get its name(label) through a script. How to do it?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the checkbox label ? "Viewport Denoising" or its variable identifier in python code ?

Comment: I mean label. If you also know how to get variable id in python code, it would be nice.